# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0' in ArcGIS Pro 3.1 SDK for .NET

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, add-in, arcgis-runtime

I have upgraded an ArcGIS Pro 3.1 Add-In from version 2.8. The Add-In uses `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` to manage a configuration file.

However, when the code tries to read the config file:

```
IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile(@"C:\Users\XXX\Data\config.json", false, true)
    .Build();
```

It throws the following error:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'Failed to load configuration from file 'C:\Users\XXX\Data\config.json'.'
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The `System.Text.Json` package is installed and the version is 7.0.0. The dll appears in the bin folder and the AddIn AssemblyCache folder. I have seen other questions about this error, but none of the answers helped (sadly). Here are some things I have tried:

1. Clean the solution and rebuild
2. Restart Visual Studio and/or the computer
3. Checked the .NET runtime and desktop runtimes are installed (from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)
4. Installed the package directly (not as a dependency) and added a `PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="7.0.0" />` to the project `.csproj` file
5. Set the build type to 'Any CPU'
6. Built as 'release'
7. Updating/Downgrading the package
8. Removing all the NuGet and reinstalling

So far nothing has worked. Does anyone have any other ideas? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution was to downgrade both `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` and `System.Text.Json` to 6.0.0. Despite that the NuGet manager recommends using 7.0.0 for both of them when targeting .NET6, and that we are using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` at 7.0.0 as well.

Setting `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` to 6.0.0 doesn't work either. Somehow this is the only setup that works.